# How does one change the colour of a div based on current time?

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors

I have javascript code that converts the color of the body based on current time but I need it to change the color of a div instead. I am not knowledgeable enough in javascript to know how to do this. I know I need to add a div to the html. The main code is bigger but I've just pulled the basics to get it to work.

**Javascript**

```
function emea() {
  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.getUTCHours()+1;

  if (n > 18 || n < 9) {
    // If time is after 6PM or before 9AM, apply night theme to 'body'
    document.body.className = "emeanight";
  }
  else {
    // Else use ‘day’ theme
    document.body.className = "emeaday";
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  emea();
});
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='tz.css'>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <title>TZ TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src='tz.js'></script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.emeaday
{
background-color:green;
}

.emeanight
{
background-color:blue;
}
```

I have tried variations of document.getelementbyid but I keep hitting a blank.

Comment: It seems strange that you are only using jQuery for onLoad and not add/remove class

Comment: Just select the div you want to change instead of the body.

Comment: `<div class="yourDiv"></div>` and the css `.emeaday .yourDiv {}`

Comment: Also note that getUTCHours() will get the time at the prime meridian. If you want it to correspond to the user's time, use getHours()

Comment: Everything worked fine for me. Silly question, but are you including a reference to `JQuery`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on @Hazzard's comment, you can also use jQuery to select your div by ID or whatever:

```
 function emea() {
     var d = new Date();
     var n = d.getUTCHours() + 1;
     if (n > 18 || n < 9) {
         // If time is after 6PM or before 9AM, apply night theme to 'body'
         $("#foo").addClass("emeanight").removeClass("emeaday");
     } else {
         // Else use ‘day’ theme
         $("#foo").addClass("emeaday").removeClass("emeanight");
     }
 }
 $(document).ready(function () {
     emea();
 });
```

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your help, I went with this answer. I'm not sure on the proper 'thanks' etiquette on this forum, let me know if i missed anything. Rgds, Kristian

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get a reference to the element in javascript then apply your code.
Try using `document.getElementById()` if your div has an ID. You could also use `document.querySelector()` passing the div's selectors to it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using jQuery, you don't need to use plain javascript to target your div. You can use $('#ID') to select the div you wish to change, and then call jQuery functions to change its class.

`function emea(){
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getUTCHours()+1;
    var divToChange = $('#divId');
    if (n > 18 || n < 9)
      // If time is after 6PM or before 9AM, apply night theme to 'body'
      divToChange.removeClass("emeaday").addClass("emeanight");
    else
      // Else use ‘day’ theme
      divToChange.removeClass("emeanight").addClass("emeanight");
}`

Answer (score 0):

Use `addClass(className)`. you can read more about addclass http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Even you can make use of `toggleClass(classname)` , here is the link for it  http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='tz.css'>
        <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <title>TZ TEST</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .emeaday { background-color:green; }
            .emeanight { background-color:blue; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var h = new Date().getHours();
            document.body.className = (9 > h || 18 < h) ? "emeanight" : "emeaday";
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use vanilla JS, you can get the div element like so:

Add a div in your html body with an id (might be easier to see if you set a height/width for the div):

```
<div id='test'>Hello<div>
```

JS:

```
function emea(){
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getUTCHours()+1;       
    if (n > 18 || n < 9) {
      // If time is after 6PM or before 9AM, apply night theme to 'body'
      //document.body.className = "emeanight";
      document.getElementById("test").className = 'emeanight';
    }
    else {
      // Else use ‘day’ theme
      //document.body.className = "emeaday";
      document.getElementById("test").className = 'emeaday';
    }
}

emea();
```